# Can a scatter plot / bubble chart be used to represent variables whose proportions are different?

Tags: visualization

I've been trying to figure out this since a while now. Perhaps I'm on the wrong direction.

Imagine a fictional scenario like the following: I'm a box planner, and have box packagers working on X different lines whose needs are different for each line.

See below some fictional data:

| ID | packed | expected | Production lines |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 24 | 35 | 1 |
| B | 12 | 20 | 2 |
| C | 48 | 90 | 3 |

At the end of the days, I'd like to visually show my packagers their efforts to incentivate them as well as the management the potential need of a more packagers if needed.

I would like to put the "ID (aka lines)" in relationship, showing how much far away they were from their objectives, and perhaps considering how many "production lines" were involved into the process.
The more the lines the less the efforts because in theory the production should have been greater.

So far I have used a weighting approach for the production lines with which I determine the size of the bubble. X and Y are respectively the packed and expected.

In my mind I was willing also to show how much was the distance from need to expected, and so long each variable is treaded separately on the X axis, the graph proposes a narrative. But I wonder if there is any change to change the way how data is treated so they will all converge to a 1:1 when needs are fully met.

Thanks for your hints.